# Problem with ant file

Tags: java, ant, build

I have this `build.xml` file http://gist.github.com/315109 . Every task runs smoothly, but **test**.

I don't know why I'm getting (if I run ant with `-v`) something like this:

> [junit] The ' characters around the
>   executable and arguments are
>
> [junit]
>    not part of the command.

**EDIT:**

As pointed out, seems like that message is irrelevant to the error in question.

The problem I'm getting is a bunch of  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

Any ideas why? all classes are in the correct source directory stated in the ant file....

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -v option tells ant to provide verbose output. The message is just information that tells you to ignore the quotes around the echoed command line and argument values.

Unless there is an error message as well, then this isn't anything to worry about, particularly if it goes away without the -v flag.

If you are not getting any test results, then the first thing I would do is try running with fork="no" in order to make the behaviour more predictable for debugging.

You might also try -debug instead of -v as it gives different output.

Good luck.